# How to exclude NULL results in a .txt file and display them in php?

Tags: php, csv, fwrite

I read a csv file that contains these values :

```
; ;WH;391;M;9353970157191;A1124;0010;TU;1; ;7/1/2019;0;0;

; ;WH;391;M;9353970157214;A1119;0090;TU;1; ;7/1/2019;0;0;

....
```

At the end I get a .txt file which is like this:

```
    MMXC1_|A0391|9353970395487|0|0

    MMXC1_|A0391|   |1|0 //$SKU_EAN NULL

    MMXC1_|A0391|9353970394879|4|2

...
```

But sometimes the $SKU_EAN is NULL because it doesn't have a corresponding sku_code

I would like to exclude lines where the $SKU_EAN is NULL from my .txt file and display them on the screen with the sku_code, and the number of the corresponding line in the csv file, how can I do that?

```
$resultat = mysqli_query($bdd, "SELECT trim(concat(concat(SKU_ITEM_VARIANT,'_'),trim(SKU_SIZE)))as sku_code , SKU_EAN  FROM dwh_dev.dwh_d_sku"); 

while ($donnees[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat)) {

    // var_dump($donnees); //array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["sku_code"]=> string(13) "A1101_0090_TU" ["SKU_EAN"]=> string(13) "9346799868270" } } array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["sku_code"]=> string(13) "A1101_0090_TU" ["SKU_EAN"]=> string(13) "9346799868270" }....
}  

$constante = "MMXC1_";

$temp = array_column($datas_mag,  'MAGCOD', 'MAGAS400');
$temp2 = array_column($donnees,  'SKU_EAN', 'sku_code');


        if (($handle = fopen("$nomcsv", "r")) !== FALSE) { 

            $firstLine = true;

            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000000, ";")) !== FALSE) 
            {   
                if(!$firstLine) {

                    $EAN = 'A'.$temp[$data[3]];

                    $SKU_EAN = $temp2[$data[6].'_'.$data[7].'_'.$data[8]];
                    var_dump($SKU_EAN); //string(13) "9353970395487" string(13) "9346799046166" NULL NULL string(13) "9346799046756"...



$data_final[] = $constante.'|'.$EAN.'|'.$SKU_EAN.'|'.$data[12].'|'.$data[13];
 var_dump($data_final); //array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "MMXC1_|A0391|9353970395487|0|0" }
                 }
                 $firstLine = false;
            }   
        }

                 $cheminfile = "//alcyons/IT/PhotoShoot/retail/CSV/TXT_Finaux/MMX".date('His').".txt";

                $fp = fopen("$cheminfile", "w");

                foreach($data_final as $data){
                   fwrite($fp,$data."\n");
                }                           

                fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Where is the array that contains the CSV data? `$donnees` or `$data`?

Comment: $donnees[] contains the results of my query and $data[] allows me to go and read the different columns of my csv file

Comment: Can you post the FIRST result from `var_dump($data_final);` (I realise it may be a big array so just the first one will do).

Comment: I changed my code so you can look at it, and yes, the array is big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this

I've assumed that your comment around `$SKU_EAN` are individual example values, so adding the following line should skip the iteration where this value is null.

```
if(is_null($SKU_EAN)) continue;
```

---

**Full code:**

```
$i = 1;

while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000000, ";")) !== FALSE) {   

    $i++;

    if(!$firstLine) {

        $EAN = 'A'.$temp[$data[3]];
        $SKU_EAN = $temp2[$data[6].'_'.$data[7].'_'.$data[8]];

        if(is_null($SKU_EAN)) {
            echo 'Can\'t find SKU_EAN for iteration number: ' . $i . '<br />';
            continue;
        }

        $data_final[] = $constante.'|'.$EAN.'|'.$SKU_EAN.'|'.$data[12].'|'.$data[13];

    }

    $firstLine = false;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! And now how to retrieve and display the $SKU_EAN NULL?

Comment: Great - remember to mark it as an accepted answer. What do you mean by "display the `$SKU_EAN` NULL"?

Comment: I've edited my question to echo the iteration number where `$SKU_EAN` is null

Comment: Does $i match the line number in the csv file?

Comment: Does your data start in the CSV at line 2?

Comment: Yes because I don't read the header but I would like to tell the users that" such SKU_EAN is missing from such line in the csv file"

Comment: I've changed `$i` in my code so that it equals 2, this should show you the exact line number now - give it a try.

Comment: I have several times the same result, for example: Can't find SKU_EAN for iteration number: 378

Comment: So line 378 in your CSV, the SKU isn't null?

Comment: Yes she is! But I have several times the line displayed while it is NULL only once

Comment: I changed my code again if you can try that, now it shouldn't show 378 multiple times, but if it's caught in a loop it'll show 379, 380, 381, etc.

Comment: It's perfect!! Thanks a lot